# Using \\ in environments inside the \begin{tabularx}

Tags: tables, align, tabularx

I have the following code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{ m{4cm}  X }
        & \textbf{Derivations} \\
        $v=v_0+at$              & line 1\hrule \\
        $x=x_0+v_0t+½at^2$      & \begin{align*}
                                v=&equation 1 \\
                                =&equation 2 \\
                                =&equation 3
                                \end{align*} \hrule \\
        $v^2-v_0^2=2a(x-x_0)$   & line 3 \hrule \\
        $x-x_0=½t(v_0-v)$       & line 4
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

The `tabularx` environment allows further sub-environments like the `\begin{align*}...`. I use the `align*` environment to make line breaks between equations and have them aligned along the equal-signs.

The problem is now that I use `\\` to make the equation line breaks *inside* this sub-environment. Apparently the `tabularx` environment still detects this and responds to it. Since `\\` is already a signal for the end-of-row for the table, this is not tolerated.

How can I get around this? Is there another method that I can use for the same purpose (multiple aligned equation lines) where this `\\` can be avoided?

Comment: what about `\par` and `\newline`

Comment: @touhami I have to use `\\` for the linebreak in that environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has come up before, it's a "feature" of amsmath, but you can hide the environment in `{}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]% never just [h]
    \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{ m{4cm}  X }
        & \textbf{Derivations} \\
        $v=v_0+at$              & line 1\hrule \\
        $x=x_0+v_0t+½at^2$      & {\begin{align*}
                                v=&equation 1 \\
                                =&equation 2 \\
                                =&equation 3
                                \end{align*}} \hrule \\
        $v^2-v_0^2=2a(x-x_0)$   & line 3 \hrule \\
        $x-x_0=½t(v_0-v)$       & line 4
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```